# Searching Row number of particular observation in R

Tags: r

How can i search the row number for a particular observation in r.
I have stock price data of a company from 1972-2009. But i only want data from 1995-2005 for further analysis. So I want to know row number for 01-01-1995 & 31-12-2005.

I tired using which.max , which() but didn't get desired result

Answer (score 1):

We can do with extracting the 'year' from the 'date' create a logical index and then wrap with `which`

```
which(format(as.Date(df1$Date, "%d-%m-%Y"), "%Y") %in% 1995:2005)
```

Comment: Thanks for response,
I understood your solution,however Can there be a easier way, I come from non coding background it gets difficult for me to create logical index at times.